# 'Bad Request' on POST form submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In `index.html` there is a form that, once submitted, should redirect to `results.html` to render some info based on the form submission. However, I keep getting `Bad Request` HTTP response and using other solutions on SO give me `Cannot POST`.

This was working when all routers were in the `app.js` file. Now, I've separated routing for each page and now I cannot reach `/results`. Beforehand, the form (which is on `/`) submitted a POST request to `/` and then redirected to `/results`, but I am trying to directly redirect to `/results`

index.js:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res)  {
    res.sendFile('/public/pages/index.html', {root: './'});
});
```

results.js (I import a module search and call a function to render stuff):

```
router.post('/', search.issues, function(req, res) {
    console.log("In results");
    let searchResult = req.body.searchResult;
    res.render('results.html', {
        results : searchResult.length,
        searchTerm : req.body.searchTerm,
        searchResult : searchResult,
        category : req.body.category
    });
});
```

app.js, where I import and use the routers:

```
/** begin importing all routes */
const indexRoute = require('./api/routes/index'),
    aboutRoute = require('./api/routes/about'),
    resultsRoute = require('./api/routes/results');

/** begin middleware use for routes */
app.use('/', indexRoute);
app.use('/about', aboutRoute);
app.use('/results', resultsRoute);
```

index.html form:

```
<form method="post" action="/results">
```

I should be redirected to results.html to render, but I get a `Bad Request` HTTP code. My routes are in `src/routes/` and `results.html` is in `src/views`. `index.html` is in `src/public/pages/index.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **body-parser**, because by default express does not know how to handle json files and you should use **express.static** to serve your html files.

Here am i mapping the content of the html folder to the localhost:5000/. So you could place a form.html file inside this folder and access it from **localhost:5000/form.html**.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes');

app.use('/', express.static('html'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Initilizing routes.
routes(app);


app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 5000");
});
```

Then in your routes.js file:

```
var routesAPI = function(app){

app.get('/product'), function (req, res) {   
    console.log("GET products route");
}

app.post('/products', function (req, res) {
    let product = req.body;
    console.log(product);
    res.json(product);
});

}

module.exports = routesAPI;
```

Comment: I do have a body parser and serve the static files similarly, they have no problem being delivered (I do not show the full app.js file). When all of my routing functions were in the app.js, the POST function had no problem being called, now that the routes are separated it does not work.

Comment: I see Erick. I will check again!

Comment: Hi Erick! I have just updated my answer showing how to place your routes in a separated file. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please alter the router sequence,

```
app.use('/about', aboutRoute);
app.use('/results', resultsRoute);
app.use('/', indexRoute);
```

By default, any routing was accessing the `/` route.